# Proper use of polymorphism / inheritance in Open API 3

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, swagger, openapi

I am missing something in the proper use of polymorphism in Open API 3.

In [the specification document (3.0.2)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#discriminator-object), an example uses `oneOf`, and optionally the `Discriminator` block :

```
    MyResponseType:  
     oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'  
     discriminator:
        propertyName: petType
```

In this scenario, the only constraint that `Cat`, `Dog` and `Lizard` must satisfy is the mandatory field `petType`, and a predetermined value.
Later on, one can read :

> To avoid redundancy, the discriminator MAY be added to a parent schema
>   definition, and all schemas comprising the parent schema in an allOf
>   construct may be used as an alternate schema.

I find it nice since it offers a proper use of the natural inheritance of the 3 entities :

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
      - petType
      properties:
        petType:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: petType
        mapping:
          dog: Dog
    Cat:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
etc
```

By the way, the spec is a bit ambiguous with

> The discriminator object is legal only when using one of the composite
>   keywords oneOf, anyOf, allOf

`Pet` does not contains any of these keywords !

However, this second example does not show the consequences on the `MyResponseType` block.

1. Does it stay the same ? If so, what should be generated, say, in Java ? A `MyResponseType` and a `Pet` classes ? What should the `MyResponseType` class look like ?
2. Should `MyResponseType` be removed from the file, and `Pet` used instead ? If so, the swagger editor is not capable of tracing the subtypes anymore...
3. Then, should we add the `oneOf` to the `Pet` schema, so that the swagger editor can display the subtypes ? I've tried, it works, and validators say it's Open API 3 compliant, *but* warn that a cycle gets in the way. It seems to me that this would be formally wrong : an http body with a `Cat` (petType Cat) with all the `Cat` and `Dog` properties would validate because of the `oneOf` Cat/Dog/Lizard inherited from `Pet`. Am I right to interprete it this way ?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question directly in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues